# Images and Uploading in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

So I know how to do uploading in php, especially images. What I dont know is how to turn a image into a button such that clicking on it allows you to then be presented with an upload dialog that allows you to upload an image (or another file).

The typical way of doing upload input is: `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />`

But how do I take an  `<img />` and turn it into an image upload button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use javascript for this, the principle is to hide the real file input and "click" it using javascript attached to an image

The input is positioned off the screen, if you hide it (display:none) with CSS, it will stop working in some browsers

```
<input type="file" class="file-select" name="files[]" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px" />
<img class="file-button" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cdn.bark.com/qa/b5dc2e3e/a61da61d/3185c5d0/d0bfa4e1/d7d2cff4/dd6dff79/00457b9a/1009914c/6cbe2b57/fb0d89c1/d292ac8a/d6800521/a797a21a/fe1de44a/ef665fad/f1d83fce/thumbnail_529621c60502a.jpeg"/>
```

Then we simply use javascript to say that when the image is clicked, "click" on the file input:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('.file-button').on('click', function(e){
    $('.file-select').click();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

See this JSFiddle for full demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/HhLzD/